# Aliexpress API signature algorithm and javascript

Tags: javascript, cryptojs, aliexpress

I have been working on trying to retrieve a correct signature for use in getting an access token from the aliexpress API.  The signature is appended to the end of the URL and then, if the signature is correct, it gives you back the access token, refresh token, user credentials, etc.  Unfortunately, I have not been able to get back the proper signature as per "platform standards".  I am stumped at the moment.

What I am doing in this code is calling parameters for my `app_key`, timestamp, sign method and code (retrieved from the URL and stored in local storage), sorting through them so that they are in alphabetical order, concatenating the string with no spacing, encoding the string,  then using CryptoJS to create a signature with my app_secret as the key.  This is all per documentation, however I must be doing something slightly wrong because I am not retrieving the same string as in the example.

In the example in the documentation, the signature string looks like..

D13F2A03BE94D9AAE9F933FFA7B13E0A5AD84A3DAEBC62A458A3C382EC2E91EC

While mine looks like..

FA09CDF0AA01015E5CF20B05234D25BA00203952EA00D86EEDA7A199D3483725

```js
const generateSign = () => {
  const code = localStorage.getItem("authCode");
  const params = {
    app_key: appKey,
    timestamp: timestamp,
    sign_method: sign_method,
    code: code,
  };
  console.log(params);

  const sortedParams = Object.keys(params)
    .sort()
    .reduce((acc, key) => {
      acc[key] = params[key];
      return acc;
    }, {});
  console.log(sortedParams);

  let concatenatedString = "";
  for (const key in sortedParams) {
    concatenatedString += `${key}${sortedParams[key]}`;
  }
  const apiName = "/auth/token/security/create";
  concatenatedString = apiName + concatenatedString;
  console.log(concatenatedString);

  const encodedString = encodeURIComponent(concatenatedString);
  console.log(encodedString);
  const hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(encodedString, appSecret);
  console.log(hash);
  const signature = hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex).toUpperCase();

  console.log(signature);

  return signature;
};
```

Comment: What do you currently get, and what are you supposed to get? Exactly what isn't working?

Comment: Is there any documentation for this, or are you reverse engineering?

Comment: From USA can't registry as a developer (海外版禁止写入) @ aliexpress.com, sorry can't help you.

Comment: I am supposed to get an HmacSHA256 hex that includes my app_key, a timestamp, a code retrieved from the URL and a sign method (sha256).  What I am getting is just that, but the error I receive is that it does not meet platform standards.  So I must be doing something wrong.  I am following documentation however, the documentation is only outlined in python, java, php, and .net but not in javascript.  So the exact algorithm for the code is not present.  Even though I have tried to follow the java code for the algorithm, it still is not working.  I feel like I am missing something very minor.

Comment: @BenchVue --- their new open platform allows registration from over seas actually

Comment: @Steffen here is the algorithm for the signature, if you are able to access the link https://openservice.aliexpress.com/doc/doc.htm?spm=a2o9m.11193535.0.0.2a7a7dc98tnOoH&nodeId=27493&docId=118729#/?docId=1367

Comment: have you tried to compare between [tag:cryptojs] output with any hmacsha256 out there? i remember cryptojs had some gotchas, but i can't remember what.

Comment: Why are you applying `encodeURIComponent` to the concatenated string? I don't see that step performed in the algorithm outlined in their documentation.

Comment: @Cbroe I will certainly try it without.  I was basing it off of step 4.

Comment: @BagusTesa I have not.  I will give that a go.  I was imagining that cryptojs would work just like crypto.

Comment: @CBroe trying without encodedURI I get the error message {"type":"ISP","code":"isv.402","message":"test33","request_id":"2102e91217089759162068904"} which I have no idea what it means.  Could be a step in the right direction! lol

Comment: @MattRowley the docs says [`isv`](https://openservice.aliexpress.com/doc/doc.htm?spm=a2o9m.11193535.0.0.2a7a7dc98tnOoH&nodeId=27493&docId=118729#/?docId=1372) refers to business data error. so, maybe its not the hash that fails but one of the parameters?